# IE10 adds a (non-CSS) top margin to buttons (pushing them down) when their value is set to a space character

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've got a toolbar-like feature on my website using `<input type="button" />`s with a background image as the icon and some of the buttons look better with no text, so I removed the `value`s but that messed up some other CSS (long story) so my solution was to set their `value` attribute to a space. This looks perfect in Firefox & Chrome, but in Internet Explorer (tested in version 10) it shifts the space-value buttons down to align the top of the `input` with the text of it's "sibling" `input`s.

Here's some simple HTML to replicate the "bug", the only button that breaks is the one with a space (any number of spaces still breaks to display). I can easily work-around this by using CSS or &nbsp;, but I was just curious to know if anyone's got a better solution, and/or if it's an actual bug in IE!

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body><form>
  <input type="button" value="Something" />
  <input type="button" value=" " />
  <input type="button" value="&nbsp;" />
  <input type="button" value="" />
  <input type="button" />
</form></body></html>
```

Edit: I've just noticed that Chrome does the opposite (moves the buttons UP) with the last two in that demo (no value)! Craziness.

Comment: Not that it helps particularly, but if you give it the html5 doc type it fixes it in IE10. Looks like it's something to do with the way IEs rendering buttons when it's in quirks mode

Comment: +1 on the comment from @Jerryf. IE needs a doctype to work properly, otherwise it defaults to rendering in quirks mode (usually IE5 mode).

Comment: Adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` fixes the issue in IE10, but it doesn't do anything in Chrome!